# How can I acquire data from social media to analyze it using machine learning?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, social-networking, prediction, data-acquisition

I have a project where I'm required to predict future user location so that we can provide him with location specific services as well as collect data from his device that would be used to provide a service for another user etc...

I have already developed an android app that collects some data but as social media is the richest in terms of information, I would like to make use of that. For example, if the user checks in in a restaurant and gives it a good review (on fb for example) then he is likely to go back there. Or if he tweets a negative tweet about a place then he is unlikely to go back there... these are just examples I thought of.

So my main issue is: how do I even get access to that information? I mean it's not like the user is going to send me a copy of every social media activity they have so how do I get it and is that even possible? Because I know fb, twitter and other social medias have security policies so I initially thought it couldn't be done and that only facebook gets access to their users' information to predict their likes and dislikes and show them adds and sponsored posts accordingly but when googling it, I found a lot of tools that claim to be able to provide that sort of data. How did they even acquire it and is it possible for me to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook, Twitter, etc. have well-documented APIs that may or may not allow you to access the data.

For the APIs, see the official documentation of each, because anything I write here will likely be outdated in a year or two, as their APIs change.

Don't rely on web scraping. The web sites change design more often than the API, and you will likely violate the terms-of-service.